# innerHTML doesn't work well (angular - typescript,html)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I try to make innerHTML from ts file and it doesn't work well,
the idea is to make card__timer work when there is a click on the button .

the card_timer class is SVG timer.

ts file:

```
document.querySelector(".card__timer")!.innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <div id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">
    <span>${formatTime(timeLeft)}</span>
    <span>${formatTime(timeLeft)}</span>
    </div>
</div>`;


document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(".card_button").forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (document.querySelector(".card__timer") as HTMLElement).style.display = 'block';
    document
      .querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(".card__block:not(.card__timer)")
      .forEach(function (el ) {
        el.style.display= "none"
      });
     (".card__block:not(.card__timer)"))

      startTimer()
  })
})
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like an Angular way of doing things..?

Comment: what do you mean? it's part of the code..

Comment: Too complicated and prone to various issues - you should just make a new component out of the code you want to use as innerHtml, then reference it in the template of the parent component where you want it inserted. Also try not to call methods from the view unless it has a clear trigger (like click) - because it will run several times on each load of the page.